# Error 403 while using exchangelib to access Outlook Exchange server to read emails

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read emails from the Microsoft Exchange server using EWS and exchangelib in Python for an email classification problem. But I am unable to connect to the exchange server.

I've tried specifying the version, auth_type, using a certificate (which gives a ssl verify error), using the smtp address in place of the username and it still doesn't connect.

Here is my code:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, EWSDateTime, EWSTimeZone, Configuration, DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, NTLM, ServiceAccount, Version, Build

USER_NAME = 'domain\\user12345'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL = john.doe@ext.companyname.com'
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = 'John@1234'
ACCOUNT_SERVER = 'oa.company.com'

creds = Credentials(USER_NAME, ACCOUNT_PASSWORD)
config = Configuration(server=ACCOUNT_SERVER, credentials=creds)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address=ACCOUNT_EMAIL, config=config, autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)

print('connecting ms exchange server account...')
print(type(account))

print(dir(account))
account.root.refresh()
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
TransportError: Unknown failure
Retry: 0
Waited: 10
Timeout: 120
Session: 26271
Thread: 15248
Auth type: <requests_ntlm.requests_ntlm.HttpNtlmAuth object at 0x00000259AA1BD588>
URL: https://oa.company.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
HTTP adapter: <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x00000259AA0DB7B8>
Allow redirects: False
Streaming: False
Response time: 0.28100000000085856
Status code: 403
Request headers: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.21.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '469', 'Authorization': 'NTLM 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', 'Cookie': 'ClientId=SINZWMOJKWSKDGEKASFG; expires=Fri, 26-Jun-2020 10:13:02 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly'}
Response headers: {'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'request-id': 'ae4dee8d-34e0-471c-8252-b8c1056c8ea0', 'X-CalculatedBETarget': 'pqrexch05.domain.com', 'X-DiagInfo': 'PQREXCH05', 'X-BEServer': 'PQREXCH05', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'Set-Cookie': 'exchangecookie=681afc8a0905459182363cce9a98d021; expires=Sat, 27-Jun-2020 10:13:02 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, X-BackEndCookie=S-1-5-21-1343024091-725345543-504838010-1766210=u56Lnp2ejJqBy87Iysqem5nSy8mbnNLLyZ7H0sfIysbSy5vMz8qdzcvPnpzHgYHNz87G0s/I0s3Iq87Pxc7Mxc/N; expires=Sat, 27-Jul-2019 10:13:02 GMT; path=/EWS; secure; HttpOnly', 'Persistent-Auth': 'true', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'X-FEServer': 'PQREXCH05', 'Date': 'Thu, 27 Jun 2019 10:13:01 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0'}
Request data: b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>\n<s:Envelope xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><s:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="false"><m:UnresolvedEntry>ICICIBANKLTD\\IPRU38190</m:UnresolvedEntry></m:ResolveNames></s:Body></s:Envelope>'
Response data: b''
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to configure access policy for EWS using PowerShell.

For example (to allow all apps to use REST and EWS):

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -EwsApplicationAccessPolicy EnforceBlockList -EwsBlockList $null
```

Taken from Microsoft docs on [Set-OrganizationConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/Set-OrganizationConfig?view=exchange-ps).

Please search for **EwsApplicationAccessPolicy** in the above link for more granular access control examples.